# Sails js 9.4 - assets not being copied

Tags: sails.js

First sails didn't create .tmp/public, so i did it manually. But it also doesn't copy stuff from my assets folder to my public folder. Can someone explain why that is?

## #

At that time, the answers i got weren't helping,
I've updated to 9.8 now, and i don't seem to have any problem.

## #

Answer (score 10):

I had this same issue. When running `sails lift` the .tmp folder wasn't created. What finally worked for me was installing Grunt locally in the root folder of my sails app. So just run `npm install grunt` in your sails app folder. Having Grunt installed globally with the `-g` flag was apparently not enough. After the local installation, you can run `sails lift` again, and the .tmp folder will be created.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Just ran into the exact same issue with v0.9.11.  This was the fix.

Comment: I had this issue with version 0.9.16. This fix worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

### Where do I put my css and javascript assets in sails?

Sails uses [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) to manage assets.  Some of this "management" involves syncing files between your project folder structure and the server's public folder, but as always, I'm getting ahead of myself.

The configuration of `grunt` is based upon the `Gruntfile.js` file found in the root of your sails project.  There’s a lot going on in this file, however, I’m going to concentrate on the javascript and css assets.

#### Your Project's Assets

When you first create a project, you have the option of using the `--linker` flag.  An example of using the flag would be `sails new projectName --linker`. Here’s the directory structure of the `/assets` folder under both scenarios:

**USING** the `--linker` flag

```
/assets
 /images
 /linker
  /js
  /styles
  /templates
```

**NOT USING** the `--linker` flag

```
/assets
 /images
 /js
 /styles
```

Note, you can “upgrade” a project that wasn't created with the `--linker` flag by manually creating the `/linker` folder and inserting it into your `/assets` path.  You can then add `/js`, `/styles`, and `/templates` under `/linker`.

#### The Server's Public Folder

When starting the sails server via `sails lift` the following folder structure is created/sync'd via `grunt` within the `.tmp` folder:

```
.tmp
  /public
```

If any of the other project folders (e.g. `/images`, `/js`, `/styles`, `/templates`) contain content they are copied/sync'd to the `.tmp/public`folder.  The distinction being that if a `/linker` folder exists, the `/js`, `/styles`, and an additional `/templates` folder is created under `/linker`.

#### What happens to my `layout.ejs` file?

If you use the `/linker` folder, sails will alter your `layout.ejs` file to include links to your javascript and css files.  Therefore, any page served from the project's `/views` folder will have access to the javascript and css contained in these files.

Grunt uses commented tags in `layout.ejs` to as placehodler for these links.  For example, anything placed in the `/style` folder will automatically be linked in `layout.ejs` between these two tags:

```
<!--STYLES-->    
<!--STYLES END-->
```

Anything in the `/js` folder will be linked between these two tags:

```
<!--SCRIPTS-->
<!--SCRIPTS END-->
```

Anyting in the `/templates` folder will be linked between these two tags:

```
<!--TEMPLATES-->   
<!--TEMPLATES END-->
```

#### Accessing Sail's Assets

Here's how you access the assets under either scenario:

**USING** the `/linker` folder

`/js` --> `/linker/js/yourFile.js`

`/styles` --> `/linker/styles/yourCSS.css`

**NOT USING** the `/linker` folder

`/js` --> `/js/yourFile.js`

`/styles` --> `/styles/yourCSS.css`

Comment: The problem is, nothing is being copied to my .tmp/public from my assets folder, it doesn't even create my .tmp folder

Comment: If you can, post a link to your repo and I'll have a look.

Answer (score 2):

It didn't appear that Grunt was doing **anything** on my installation including copying the assets folder. I found this post on the Google Group by Rob Wormald that finally got it working for me:

In your .sailsrc file, in the root of your project, remove the line that says "grunt" : false. That should get things working.

This was an issue with one of the generators that I believe should be corrected in the next release.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to check Gruntfile.js in your sails project root directory and everything will be much easier to understand. Here is some short explanation:

- Sails 'magic' during lift process are hidden in Grunt tasks.
- If Sails not create .tmp/public directories in your project, it can be because permissions or something similar (its happen on Windows as I know, I not have it on Linux). Solution is to create manually .tmp/public directories and to be sure that is writable.
- To get your assets copied to .tmp/public you will need to keep it inside assets/linker directory, or to update Gruntfile.js based on your specific need.

I hope this help :).

Comment: Thanks, but i've tried this already, permission, read-only, take ownership, creating linker stuff, it doesn't seem to work for some reason. It's either a security issue that i overlooked or grunt has issues with windows paths. Or... sails just doesn't execute the grunt script.

Comment: I have just had the same problem.  Trying to install a sails framework on my netbook, grunt does not seem to be creating .tmp/  Grunt is installed, running aptana studio 3 as administrator, have had success (sort of) running on desktop.  Only diff is Win7 version on netbook (Win 7 Starter).

Comment: I find I get this error for Grunt suggesting the problem is with the name of my User directory ie. "User\Harry Roach" : error: Grunt ::
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'c:\Users\Harry'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3