# Get download url of Uploaded image in Sails.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, file-upload, sails.js

I am working on an Api in Sails.js where I need to upload image to server through api and get url of that uploaded image for later use from Mobile App. For doing this, my upload codes are as follows

```
upload: function  (req, res) {

    var uploadPath = '../../assets/images' ;
    req.file('avatar').upload({ dirname: uploadPath },function onUploadComplete (err, files) {

        if (err) {
            return res.serverError(err);
        } else {
            var image = files[0];
            var fd = image.fd ;
            var index = fd.lastIndexOf('/');
            var imageName = fd.substring(index+1 , fd.length);
            return res.json({ image : '/images/' + imageName });
        }
    });
}
```

This gives me result like the following one...

```
{
    "image": "/images/bc4f03ec-0d9c-4553-b59a-9ddec427a265.jpg"
}
```

If I append the path with my localhost like this

```
http://localhost:1337/images/bc4f03ec-0d9c-4553-b59a-9ddec427a265.jpg
```

it works and image is loading in the browser. But when I deploy my application to production server, it's not working and giving me 404 error.

To solve this problem, I have already written another get action like this

```
download: function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(req.path.substr(1));
},
```

where /routes entry is

```
 'get /images/*' : {
        controller : 'FileController',
        action : 'download'
    }
```

But that didn't help, I am getting 404 at localhost.

Can anyone suggest me how can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have a `grunt` issue. The file served in your http://example.com/images/ are in fact in .tmp/public/images/ and a grunt task is syncing the asset folder with the tmp folder.

Try to run a `grunt` command in your project folder, if doesn't work try an `npm install grunt` sometimes the global npm installed grunt don't work.

Also make sure grunt can write to the folder `.tmp`;)

here are two other post which may help 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20363247/4322950
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20340354/4322950

Comment: Thanks buddy but I managed to solve the problem using skipper-gridfs.